# RAML for multiple files as output

Tags: mulesoft, raml, mule4

I am new to RAML 1.0 I want to mention multiple csv files as response.
My API will be creating multiple csv file for different entities.
I want to mention this multiple file in response in RAML. Can  you suggest what should be response for multiple files in RAML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The body in HTTP requests and reponses is formed of one payload. You should use one zip, or a tar, tar.gz, etc, file to compress the files inside one file, or use a multi-part response to convey that each file is an attachement.

Example of a zip response:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: test-attachment

/resource:
  post:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          application/zip:
```

Example of multi-part response:

```
#%RAML 1.0
title: test-attachment

/resource:
  post:
    responses:
      200:
        body:
          multipart/form-data:
            properties:
                file1:
                    type: file
                    fileTypes: ['application/csv']
                file2:
                    type: file
                    fileTypes: ['application/csv']
```

Comment: You should use one zip, or a tar, tar.gz, etc, file to compress the files inside one file :- How to mentioned this in RAML.

Comment: RAML doesn't actually implement your API. It just provides a blueprint that tools like APIKit can use to scaffold it. The RAML doesn't execute any actions. In a Mule application you could use the compression module to generate a zip file https://docs.mulesoft.com/compression-module/2.1/ though that is a different topic. This question is about RAML.
In the RAML you just mention a response with body application/zip. I'll update the answer.